# ros cell network

Tags: ros, ssh, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS on a robot with a [netgear cell modem](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/mobile-broadband/lte-modems/LB1120.aspx). The modem says it supports port forwarding but I have spent hours trying to get it to work to no avail. So instead I setup reverse ssh which works great but now I want to use RVIZ, and using it over SSH is too slow. Does anyone know how to do a 'reverse ros connection' that would establish an outbound connection to a server and allow tools like rviz, rostopic, and rqt to work from behind a firewall.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279157/ros-cell-network/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-08**:
Wouldn't a VPN make this much easier? That way your robot would be part of the same network as your PC, without any port-forwarding or other tricks needed.

I've always wanted to use [tinc-vpn](https://tinc-vpn.org) for something like this. Appears as a NIC to your OS, so should be easy with ROS.

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2018-01-08**:
Thank you. That's sounds like what I have been looking for. Also thanks for the tinc suggestion. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A VPN is the standard way to allow ROS to work on separate networks.

There's a good question and answer here: https://answers.ros.org/question/11045/how-to-set-up-vpn-between-ros-machines/

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2018-01-08**:
Awesome, I'll look into that.

I also saw someone mention that ROS2 is going to have some features relating to this, but I couldn't find any details. Do you know anything about that?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-01-08**:
ROS2 will have more granular control of transport settings such as reliability and other QoS settings which will help in cases like this. But it will still need to be routable, which is much of what the VPN provides. There are other DDS specific solutions that may be available from vendors.

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2018-01-09**:
Okay, so I got a VPN working, the robot computer is now the client. But I also want access to the GPS which is on the same LAN as the robot computer. So I think what I want is a router level VPN. Ever set one of those up? or have suggestions of a good router to use when setting up a router level VPN

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-01-09**:
You can likely setup your curren VPN endpoint to forward local network traffic through without separate hardware. It will take a little bit of adjustment of our network topology but the computer's VPN is fully capable of doing that.

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2018-01-09**:
Hot dog! that sounds like a good idea to me :) I was already redesigning the robot in my head to fit these large routers inside.